# Online Calendar

Tags: calendar

Is it possible to develop an online calendar, if a user clicks on 'Import', all the events should automatically get imported into outlook or iCal?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/iCalendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less. Certainly you can provide data in the [standard iCal format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) (and it is used to nice effect on http://conferences.yapceurope.org — having selected which talks you wish to attend at a multitrack conference, it will generate a custom iCal file for you).

That works with Google Calendar and with Apple iCal. I have no idea what Microsoft Outlook supports.

Comment: RFC2445 is obsolete. If you are looking for the standard use [RFC5545](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545). There is a lot of good information at [CalConnect Website](https://www.calconnect.org/) and [Devguide](http://devguide.calconnect.org)

Answer (score 1):

Importing data into Outlook or iCal can be done using a suitable export format. Direct import would require writing a browser plugin, it's possible but probably not feasible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I need some solution that will help directly importing events into outlook with out any manual work or eve any desk top app.